# Boundedness of derivaticves

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If $b,f\in C^4(\overline\Omega)$, $\Omega=(0,1)$ and suppose $v(x)=f(x)/b(x)$ for all $x\in \Omega$ and $b(x)\geq\beta >0$ for all $x\in \overline\Omega$. Why is that for $0\leq k\leq4$, $$|v^{(k)}(x)|\leq C, \forall x\in\overline\Omega\;?$$ For some constant $C$.

Comment: That only holds when $\exists c > 0$ with $\lvert b(x)\rvert \geqslant c$ for all $x$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, thanks I had omitted the condition on $b$. How can I prove this or which theorem is used to justify the claim.

Comment: Just use the quotient rule for the derivative. Iterate, and you see that $v^{(k)} = \frac{p}{q}$ where $q$ is a power of $b$, and $p$ is a polynomial expression in the $f^{(n)}$ and $b^{(n)}$ for $n \leqslant k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not, unless you also assume that $b\neq 0$ on $\bar\Omega$, but if that is the case, then $v\in C^4$ too, so derivatives of order up to 4 are bounded on the compact set $\bar\Omega$.

Comment: could you give reference to the proof.

Comment: Which part? It's fairly obvious that the quotient of two $C^4$ functions is $C^4$ (on the set where it is defined). If you don't see it, start differentiating. Also, I am sure that you know that a continuous function attains a maximum and a minimum on a compact set.